# How to disable GC logs rotation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-11

I used the `-Xlog:gc:file` option in my script file to log GC data in a file and I do not want this file to rotate everytime I execute the script file.
However with the following property I can see the file is creating PrintGC.log.X (X is a number) files each time I execute the script file.

```
$JVM_MEM_OPTS \
    -Xlog:gc:file="$CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/printGC.log":time \
```

Any help that can disable this file rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Java 11+ logging options, and asking about Java 11.

In Java 11 (and later) you need this:

```
-Xlog:gc:file="$CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/printGC.log"::filecount=0:time
```

According to [Enable Logging with the JVM Unified Logging Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5), the `::filecount=0` should disable log rotation.